# Grouping event with fs2.Stream

Tags: scala, functional-programming, stream, fs2

I have event stream as follows:

```
sealed trait Event

val eventStream: fs2.Stream[IO, Event] = //...
```

I want to group this events received within a single minute (i.e from 0 sec to 59 sec of every minute). This sounds pretty straightforward with `fs2`

```
val groupedEventsStream = eventStream groupAdjacentBy {event => 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(System.currentTimeMillis())
}
```

The problem is that the ***grouping function is not pure***. It uses `currentTimeMillis`. I can workaroud this as follows:

```
stream.evalMap(t => IO(System.currentTimeMillis(), t))
  .groupAdjacentBy(t => TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(t._1))
```

The thing is that adds clumsy boilerplate with tuples I'd like to avoid. Is there any other solutions?

Or maybe using impure function is not that bad for such a case?

Answer (score 2):

You could remove some of the boilerplate by using [cats.effect.Clock](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/clock.html):

```scala
def groupedEventsStream[A](stream: fs2.Stream[IO, A])
                          (implicit clock: Clock[IO], eq: Eq[Long]): fs2.Stream[IO, (Long, Chunk[(Long, A)])] =
  stream.evalMap(t => clock.realTime(TimeUnit.MINUTES).map((_, t)))
    .groupAdjacentBy(_._1)
```